# Is there a way to allow all external ip connections (i.e ipv6 as well as ipv4) in FreeRadius?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, freeradius

I need to accept all incoming connections to the FreeRadius server be it ipv6 or ipv4.
I know that we can allow all ipv4 clients with:

```
client 0.0.0.0/0 {
  secret = abcde
  shortname = xxxx
}
```

How to accept all ipv6 addresses as well on the same server?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

Add the following if not present to **radiusd.conf**

```
listen {

    type = auth
    ipaddr = *
    port = 0
}

listen {
    ipaddr = *
    port = 0
    type = acct
}

listen {
    ipv6addr = ::
    port = 0
    type = auth
}

listen {
    ipv6addr = ::
    port = 0
    type = acct
}
```

And add the following to **clients.conf**

```
client 0.0.0.0/0 {
    shortname = allv4client
    secret = testing123
}

client ::/0 {
    shortname = allv6client
    secret = testing123
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be

> client whatever {
>     ipaddr = 0.0.0.0/0
>     secret = abcde
>     shortname  = xxxx
>    }

then

> client whateverv6 {
>     ipv6addr = ::
>     secret = abcde
>     shortname  = xxxx
>    }

Comment: Yes, the above is correct.

Comment: Is that really correct? It looks inconsistent to me that for v4 you specify a prefix and for v6 you specify a single address? Why should it not read `ipv6addr = ::/0` instead?

Comment: Possibly, if you can confirm it, you're more than welcome to edit my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

You need freeradius version 2.0 and above.
Try looking at clients.conf

Comment: I have already looked at clients.conf . Have never confronted with ipv6 addresses. Any help would be great.